# Implementing a .NET application in ISV MS CRM 4.0

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I'm trying to create a small application within CRM in the ISV folder. 
I created a new application using Visual studio 2008. The only thing it does is `Response.Write("Hello world!")` in the onLoad-function. I compiled it and uploaded it to a virtual folder (app) in the ISV directory in CRM. 
If I now go to crm.mycrm.nl:5555/ISV/app I get:

> 'Microsoft.Crm.WebServices.Crm2007.CookieAndSoapHeaderAuthenticationProvider,
>   Microsoft.Crm.WebServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' doesn't exist. Parameter name:
>   Microsoft.Crm.WebServices.Crm2007.CookieAndSoapHeaderAuthenticationProvider,
>   Microsoft.Crm.WebServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35

With stack trace

```
[ArgumentException: 'Microsoft.Crm.WebServices.Crm2007.CookieAndSoapHeaderAuthenticationProvider, Microsoft.Crm.WebServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' doesn't exist.
Parameter name: Microsoft.Crm.WebServices.Crm2007.CookieAndSoapHeaderAuthenticationProvider, Microsoft.Crm.WebServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]
   Microsoft.Crm.Authentication.BaseAuthenticationSettings.CreateType(String typeName, Type requiredBaseType) +265
   Microsoft.Crm.Authentication.BaseAuthenticationSettings.CreateProvider(String typeName, IDictionary`2 configuration) +28
   Microsoft.Crm.Authentication.AuthenticationPipelineSettings.LoadPipeline() +262
   Microsoft.Crm.Authentication.AuthenticationPipelineSettings.get_AuthenticationProvider() +16
   Microsoft.Crm.Authentication.AuthenticationEngine.Execute(Object sender, EventArgs e) +524
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +68
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I fixed it. The thing is, you have to put your assemblies into the CRMWeb folder, and your aspx file into the ISV folder.