# accessing ASP.NET web page in IFRAME in CRM 4.0

Tags: dynamics-crm

I am trying to use a asp.net web app in IFrame in CRM. I have created a simple web app in asp.net which is displaying "hello" on screen. I have published this web app in ISV folder in WEBCRM. But I'm still getting this error:

```
'Microsoft.Crm.WebServices.Crm2007.CookieAndSoapHeaderAuthenticationProvider, Microsoft.Crm.WebServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' doesn't exist.
Parameter name: Microsoft.Crm.WebServices.Crm2007.CookieAndSoapHeaderAuthenticationProvider, Microsoft.Crm.WebServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
```

Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

See [Implementing a .NET application in ISV MS CRM 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872793/implementing-a-net-application-in-isv-ms-crm-4-0). Does that do it?

Answer (score 0):

you probably need IISRESET on the server!